# CarrierWave fog, making s3 uploads public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am using CarrierWave with Fog for my Rails app to uploads my image to AWS S3 bucket. My config as follow:

```
 CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'KEY',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'SECRET',
    :region                 => 'us-west-2'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'bucket101'
  config.fog_public = true
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}"}
end
```

The upload is success, but I can't view the uploaded image on the browser. This is what I get.

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you see the file uploaded in the S3 Console? What are the permissions?

`config.fog_public = true` should have enabled public read. Note: that config has to be set (and the initializer re-run) before you do your upload in order to have an effect.

Comment: Note that the S3 bucket will also need a policy to allow any anonymous user to read: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2